# Deleting key right after appending on list

Tags: python

I have here a sample code, appending the dictionary and deleting its key right after append

```
def test():
    x = []

    sample_dict = dict(
        x=2,
        b=1,
    )

    x.append(sample_dict)

    del sample_dict['x']

    print(x)

test() 
# result [{'b': 1}]
```

the only problem is that even if I append the dictionary before deleting its key, its still deleting the key even though I arranged it to delete right after appending the dictionary.

any idea on how can I achieve appending the dictionary first before deleting its key. thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? This doesn't make any sense to me. If you delete a key from a dict, you delete it from the list that references the dict too. If you want the list containing the dict to not be affected by the `del` operation, you need to make a copy of the dict first.

Comment: @YeongJongLim I'm trying to append the dictionary with its properties but what I want is to delete the property x right after appending it on the list

Comment: What's your expect output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *basic issue* faced while handling Python Objects. Equating or Appending Python Objects **links them** as the **reference is copied instead of the value**

So, your code `x.append(sample_dict)` is actually directly referencing the `sample_dict` instead of just copying its data. Hence, any changes to `sample_dict` will also be reflected inside the list as the list is just holding the reference to the same dict

To resolve this just make an immediate copy of the `sample_dict` like this

```
x.append(dict(sample_dict))
```

So, now, on running your code with the modification:

```
>>> def test():
    x = []

    sample_dict = dict(
        x=2,
        b=1,
    )
    x.append(dict(sample_dict))
    del sample_dict['x']

    print(x)

>>> test()
[{'x': 2, 'b': 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand, replacing `x.append(sample_dict)` by `x.append(sample_dict.copy())` should solve your problem.

Comment: @Beginner Is this solution working for you?

Comment: its not the result I wanted

Comment: It should work just fine. The problem was that the dict inside and outside the list were actually the same, but that changes if you create a copy.